# PHP: How to convert a partial date (dd-mm) to time?

Tags: php

I got this .csv file where I have employee number, name and birthday. Birthday comes in dd-mm format (I live in Mexico), how can I convert it to proper date, so I can call `date` function `date('y-m-d', $date)` in order to store it in the database?

Comment: An accurate date? Do you know their age? What are your expectations with this?

Comment: I don't care about the year, only the month-day combination (or day-month in this case), so I can compare against month-day of today and inform of a birthday

Comment: [`date_create_from_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: Of course I can do a function to do the translation, but I was looking if a builtin function could handle this, maybe a combination of strftime()

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't even know this function exists! I'll check it!

Comment: Where are the other two great responses I received? I came to give the correct answer check, and they are no longer here.

Answer (score 2):

You can't! At least not reliably. A date must contain the year.

Consider this example:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m', '29-02');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d'); // 2019-03-01
```

If an employee's birthday is on the 29th of February and you store it in DB as Date then you are loosing information. To keep the original information intact you need to store it in the format you have received it in, as a VARCHAR field of suitable length.

Comment: Ohhhh you're right! I never consider 2/29 (I never remember it!), yes I think I can format today's date as dd-mm (in my case) and then compare that to the stored varchar